# Teradata XMLPUBLISH_STREAM: Group multiple times?

Tags: xml, xslt, teradata

I'm trying to generate xml files from the database using the Teradata stored procedure XMLPUBLISH_STREAM. From the examples on the website, I can see, that there is the possibility of grouping via "teradata_group".
I need to group on different columns in different parts of the xml.
Is this possible?

Example

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 2012-01-01 |
| 1 | x | 2020-04-03 |
| 2 | y | 1999-01-01 |

My desired output should look like this:

```
<xml>
 <elem id="1" name="x">
  <date>2012-01-01</date>
  <date>2020-04-03</date>
 </elem>
 <elem id="2" name="y">
  <date>1999-01-01</date>
 </elem>
</xml>
```

Unfortunately I am not able to create these "inner" date-elements, because I use a "teradata_group" for the id and I am not able to use another "group by" or "xsl:for-each" inside this group. Since I never used this stored procedure before, my question is: is this even possible or can I only "group once"?

Comment: You can connect to the teradata database using oledb (https://www.connectionstrings.com/teradata/).  So you can write a powershell script that performs a query and then create the xml file using powershell.